# Stream video from one app to another in OS X (Software video input device)

Tags: macos, video, streaming

Is there any way to take a video stream from one application, for example VLC Media Player, and present that video stream to other applications as a video input source?

For example, could I broadcast a video file from my hard disk to a website that allows video conferencing using a Flash applet?

Basically, I'm looking for something like [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/), but for video streams. Is this possible?

Comment: @random - nice edits. tags especially. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CamTwist](http://allocinit.com/index.php?title=CamTwist) does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

VLC itself can serve video streams on your local network.  See the Streaming/Exporting Wizard in its File menu.